# How do I setup JS code completion for a react native project on intellij?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, react-native

React-native organizes its project like :

```
android
--build.gradle
--settings.gradle
ios
node_modules
index.android.js
index.ios.js
```

It's a little messy and requires editing js, java and objective c code, and the android studio does not support any javascript code completion. So I decided to use IntelliJ.

The problem is that if I open up at the root level, IntelliJ can't run Gradle, it will say `Error running build (1): Module 'ReactLearning' is not backed by gradle`

However, if I open up at `./android` in either android studio or IntelliJ, it works fine and I can see all the external libraries and code completion. But now I can't edit any of the code at the root level. I could have 2 editors open one at the root and one specifically for android, but then the IDEs are constantly overwriting each other's files.

Is there something I can do to tell the IDE/ Gradle that the relevant project is one subdirectory down?

Comment: This is a massive pain for me, did you ever find a solution for it?

Comment: No, I have 0 solutions for this unfortunately. I think having 2 editors open might be the only thing we can do right now and maybe telling Android studio to no do as many file changes.

Comment: Overtime, building RN apps I figured the best and practical approach would be to use IntelliJ Ultimate to open the root of the RN project to edit the JS side(App.js, components etc), if you want to edit Android, use Android Studio(important: root of the project is android, NOT RN project), and if you want to edit iOS, Xcode is the way to go(Remember to open .workspace inside iOS).

Answer (score 1):

When you create a React Native project, an Android project is created inside its file tree:

[image]

Now, you can open the Android project using IntelliJ Idea or Android studio, with the path:

```
/path/to/untitled/android
```

And the untitled project which has been created with `react-native init` using WebStorm, which has JS support, with the path:

```
/path/to/untitled
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tabnine](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12798-tabnine-ai-code-completion-js-java-python-ts-rust-go-php--more) Plugin. It Has Great AI Auto-completion Out of the Box.

Answer (score 1):

React Native project consists of 3 parts

1. Your JS source
2. Android project which is technically separate android project with a link to your js bundle
3. IOS project, the same as Android but for IOS

From my experience, it is better to use Android Studio and XCode if you want to set up and change something within the native parts of your project.